# What is this PCV hose connector near the throttle body?

Tags: buick, pcv-valve, century

I have a 1994 Buick Century 3.1L V6

I know that the PCV hoses in my car need some TLC; that fact is readily apparent because someone has liberally applied zip ties to some of them to keep them in place.

In preparation of changing both the hoses and the PCV valve, I was looking everything over and tracing the hoses around to see what exactly I needed to buy for replacement.

While inspecting closer I found this piece connected to the PCV hose near my throttle body that inserts into the air intake manifold. Not only are there zip ties holding the hose together, but it appears that someone's also tried to use superglue to hold it together.

The white spot on this connector is hard and crystalline, like dry superglue:
[image]

Since this car is my only way around, I was too afraid of the thing crumbling to pieces if I handled it too much, so I didn't want to pull it apart to get a better look at it.

I haven't been able to figure out what this thing is called to make any headway in searching for a replacement. What is this peice called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a **PVC valve hose** assembly. They are inexpensive (less than $10 in my area) and fairly straight forward to replace. This connects the PCV valve to the manifold (the connector you pointed out) and also continues back to a vacuum manifold behind the engine.

[image]

Had to replace this on my daughter's car that has the same engine. The connectors were dried out and cracked. This caused a vacuum leak and a CEL for a lean code.

It took me about 30 minutes to replace because the bracket over it has to be taken loose and the tube routed the same way as the original.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find one at Auto Zone. I wasn't able to find them originally because in their database these are not listed as being a fit for a '94 Century, but they are listed as a fit for a '95 Century. After looking at some Google images of 95 Century engine bays it looks exactly the same so I'm going to pick one of these up and give it a try.

Comment: Also, for anyone in the future, you can easily find this item by asking for Dorman/Help part #46014. Auto Zone, Advanced Auto Parts, and O'Reilly's all carry these for $8.99.

Comment: The reviews on this product complain of poor build quality and early failure, so FWIW, you may want to buy this from Advanced Auto Parts or O'Reilly's because they offer a 1-year warranty while Auto Zone doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a "tee piece or connector" - this is where the depression comes from to absorb the air/gas/mixture from the crankcase into the intake.